# possible to have model in Mongoid/Rails with a field that varies in number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to create a questionnaire app in Rails using Mongoid. I keep stumbling over the database setup because I'm new to things.

I want the users to be able to create questions with the possibility for varying numbers of answers. Some questions might have two possibilities: true, false. Some might have four or five possibilities.

So I've tried to create a question model and an answer model, then embed the answers in the question. I've tried a model with question:string answer-a:string answer-b:string answer-c:string and so on. But both approaches seem stupid and unwieldy.

Is there a way to create a model that allows someone to create a question field and an answer field, but such that the answer field can have multiples? So, create question, add an answer, and keep adding answers until they've finished their multiple choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If answers are just strings then you could use an [array field](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/fields.html):

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  #...
  field :answers, :type => Array
end
```

If answers have some internal structure (perhaps you want to track when they were created or changed or whatever), then you could use [`embeds_many`](http://mongoid.org/docs/relations/embedded/1-n.html) and two models:

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  #...
  embeds_many :answers
end

class Answer
  include Mongoid::Document
  #...
  embedded_in :question
end
```

Either one will let you work with `q.answers` in a natural list-like way so rendering such things is a simple matter of `<% q.answers.each do |a| %>` and you could [`shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) the answers to display them in a random order.

Comment: Thanks mu. I already made the :type => Array attempt, but what I'm struggling with is the form. I still only get one field for answers. I guess I was hoping that the scaffold would automagically create a little + plus sign next to the answer field. Click that and you get another answer field, and so on until you've got all your answer choices.

Comment: @charliemagee: AFAIK you have to do that yourself, it should only take a couple lines of jQuery, just a quick `.clone` and `.append`.

Comment: Thanks mu, I'll try that out.

Comment: I got the cloning of fields bit to work with `$("#plusanswer").prev().clone().insertBefore("#plusanswer");` but I get an error that it's expecting an array not a string. And my last field is the only one it takes. The others are getting ignored.

Comment: The server is complaining about a string where it expects an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you want dynamically generated forms for nested models, I suggest following this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

The RailsCast method uses application helpers to dynamically generate the new objects.

I tend to prefer @mu's method of using jQuery to create form elements.  The nice thing about Rails is that, when passing nested attributes, you can give it whatever index you want.  And so I'll generate a new form with an index of, say, `Time.now.to_s` and no ID parameter.  And so my controller receives a parameter that looks like this:

```
{"question" => {"answers_attributes" => { "1234567" => { "description" => "New answer" } } } }
```